# How do I sync offline data back to a remote database

Tags: database, github, nosql, serverless, offline-mode

Let's say for example, I'm creating a app using GitHub api to have CRUD functionalities for my gists.

One feature that I want is an offline functionality that allows the user to manage their gists even offline, and once there's network connection starts doing automatic data sync to and from the remote database(GitHub) in the background.

Some things that I want to know are:

1. Where is the best place to store local data?
2. The logic on how would that work
3. Any library that would do it automatically
4. Is the kind of db matters in this case? NoSql vs SQL?
5. Where does server less architecture fit into this

I'm sorry if I have a lot of questions regarding about this, I just want to learn how to do it, the logic behind it and not just use a library without understanding the pieces to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: Try to refine your question to very specific things and you'll get better response from SO. Id recommend asking general questions like this on one of the Reddit coding groups.  Maybe post #1 as a question alone.